# How to redirect url to default when $location:badpath in Angular JS 1

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When I enter a url where after the '\' is another '\'. For example : http://localhost:8080/#!//test. It will produce an error of $location:badpath. How to redirect it to a default route if a user do this?

```
app.config(function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider) {
$routeProvider
    .when('/test', {
        templateUrl: 'project/view/test.html',
        controller: 'TestController'
    })
    .otherwise(
        {
            redirectTo: '/dashboard'
        }
    );
```

Comment: whats your routes? beneath them add a route with path '**' and redirect it to desired route

Comment: .when('/test', {
            templateUrl: 'project/view/test.html',
            controller: 'TestController'
        })
        .otherwise(
            {
                redirectTo: '/dashboard'
            }
        );

Comment: I tried adding a path with '**' it still doesnt work

Comment: show us your routing code please

Comment: Already edited it

Comment: Moreover make it clear that either you working with angular 2+ or angular js . Because they both are totally different